# How to return a Boolean or just a promise that notifies when authentication succeeded?

Tags: string, react-native, promise, fingerprint, touch-id

I have implemented the code for Fingerprint authentication in `React Native` using [`react-native-fingerprint-scanner`](https://github.com/hieuvp/react-native-fingerprint-scanner) and its working fine. My concern might sound quite stupid but I am actually stuck on this when authentication succeeds I have no idea how to check that so that I can trigger a `setState` there. This code is just returning a string:

```
FingerprintScanner
        .authenticate((description, onAttempt) => {
            if (description) {
                this.setState({ Authenticated: true })
            }
            //description: 'Log in with Biometrics'
        })
        .then(() => {
            this.props.onAuthenticate();
        })
```

**Note: the execution never reacher `.then()` callback otherwise I would have just set the state there. No idea why it does that!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before calling the Authenticate or afterwards, I need to call this method to release the cache:

```
FingerprintScanner.release();
```

This way the user can Cancel and retry anytime.

Answer (score 0):

```
FingerprintScanner
  .authenticate({ description: 'Scan your fingerprint on the device scanner to continue' })
  .then(() => {
    //put your set state here
    Alert.alert('Authenticated successfully');
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    Alert.alert(error.message);
  });
}
```

I hope that helps

Comment: It never reaches .then({}) . Sorry I did not mention that in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you do not read [the docs example](https://github.com/hieuvp/react-native-fingerprint-scanner#example) very well. pay attention to the below codes:

```js
componentDidMount() {
  FingerprintScanner
    .authenticate({ // calling the fingerprint authentication pop-up and it waits for your acts
      description: 'the description for your user that what does he/she to do',
    })
    .then(() => { // successful callback
      this.props.handlePopupDismissed(); // close the auth pop-up
      // here, do what you want after successful authentication passing
    })
    .catch((error) => { // failure callback (fallback)
      this.props.handlePopupDismissed(); // close the auth pop-up
      // here, do what you want after failing the authentication by user
    });
}
```

The comments inside the above codes describe everything obviously.

Comment: no actually I did read it carefully, however, it doesnt work as it is supposed to. It never reaches .then({}) callback, thats why I was trying it before that.